# Bash parsing outputs to variables

Tags: string, bash, awk, jpeg

I'm trying a sort my photo's into portrait and landscape. I have come up with a command that prints the size dimensions of the jpegs:

```
identify -format '%w %h\n' 1234.jpg 
1067 1600
```

If I was using it in a bash script to move all landscape pictures to a another folder I would expect it to be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop through file (this is psuedo code!!)
for f in ~/pictures/
do
 # Get the dimensions (this is the bit I have an issue with)
 identify -format '%w %h\n' $f | awk # how do I get the width and height?
 if $width > $hieght
  mv ~/pictures/$f ~/pictures/landscape/$f
 fi
done
```

Been looking at the awk man page, but I can't seem to find the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need AWK. Do something like this:

```
identify -format '%w %h\n' $f | while read width height
do
    if [[ $width -gt $height ]]
    then
        mv ~/pictures/$f ~/pictures/landscape/$f
    fi
done
```

Comment: That's the ticket, whilst reading the awk man again it did occur to me there may be a better way. Thank you.

Comment: @Ne0: The variable `$f` should be quoted in each place it appears since image filenames frequently include whitespace. Since you're using Bash, you should use this for integer comparison: `if (( width > height ))`. Note that, while in this case it works, piping a command into `while` creates a subshell which means any variable values set within will be lost when the loop exits. In cases where this matters, use process substitution: `while ... done < <(identify ...)` and the variable values will be available after the loop completes.

Comment: what is the while loop for? `identify` doesn't seem to put out multiple lines.

Comment: Otherwise I need to group the read and if within a (). The loop does it. Basically you are right, but I use the while loop as single solution to many cases. It's quite convenience :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array`:

```
# WxH is a array which contains (W, H)
WxH=($(identify -format '%w %h\n' $f))
width=${WxH[0]}
height=${WxH[1]}
```

Comment: Wow, all the stuff I don't know about bash :)

Comment: Don't put dollar signs on the left hand side of an assignment.

Comment: I sometimes use the positional parameters: `set -- $(identify ...); width=$1; height=$2`

Answer (score 1):

```
format=`identify -format '%w %h\n' $f`;
height=`echo $format | awk '{print $1}'`;
width=`echo $format | awk '{print $2}'`;
```

Answer (score -2):

Goofballs, now for the "doh, obvious":

```
# use the identify format string to print variable assignments and eval
eval $(identify -format 'width=%w; height=%h' $f)
```